# Create and delete text posts in the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I need to write down and delete posts in the blockchain instead of the usual database.

You need two fields, text and description.

I can not find any information on this, where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a smart contract in solidity language and deploy it onto the network. Then you will be able to manipulate with the data submitting transactions to the contract.
The official Ethereum [smart contract tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter) is a good place to start.